# Error while typing * in insert mode neovim

Tags: neovim

I am getting an error while typing `*` in insert mode.

[image]

Neovim version: v0.9.0-dev-1301+g5bf2f4b3c-dirty

I can see that `*` is mapped by neovim itself. Checking `:map *` shows that it is mapped `y/\V<C-R>"<C-R>` for `x` mode. I tired doing `:unmap *` but it doesn't work.

Edit: This is most probably due to nvim-cmp autocompletion plugin. `:autocmd TextChangedI` produces this

[image]

I think I am doing something wrong with my setup because this is a very popular autocompletion plugin and I don't see any issues related to this in the repo.

Comment: Maybe try to update to a stable release? https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/stable

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

When setting up `nvim-cmp`, in global `sources` key of setup table DON'T put `cmp-cmdline` as a gloabl source. Instead, just add `cmp-cmdline` for the cmdline setup function.